# Upgrading Java Security Policy Class for Legacy RMI Application

Tags: java, security, permissions, rmi

I've been performing maintenance upgrades a legacy Java application (over a decade old) that was originally developed for Java 2 or 3, and I've encountered something that has been killing me for a week now.

The application implements its own Policy named PolicyManager. This class extends javax.security.auth.Policy. The docs tell me that was deprecated and replaced with java.security.Policy in Java 4, so I made the effort to switch this out. I replaced the import and updated the getPermissions method to accept a java.security.ProtectionDomain, rather than javax.security.auth.Subject and java.security.CodeSource.

My class now looks like:

```
//import javax.security.auth.Policy;
import java.security.Policy;

public class PolicyManager extends Policy
{
    @Override
    public synchronized void refresh()
    {
        PermissionManager.getInstance().clearAll();
    }

    @Deprecated
    public PermissionCollection getPermissions( Subject subject, CodeSource cs )
    {
        PermissionCollection permissions = null;
        Iterator<?> iterator = subject.getPrincipals().iterator();
        Principal principal = null;
        while( iterator.hasNext() )
        {
            principal = (Principal)iterator.next();
            PermissionCollection principalPerm = null;
            try
            {
                principalPerm = PermissionManager.getInstance().
                            getPrincipalPermissions(principal.getClass().getName(),
                                        principal.getName(), cs, false);
            }
            catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (permissions == null)
            {
                permissions = principalPerm;
            }
            else
            {
                Enumeration<?> en = principalPerm.elements();
                Permission permission = null;
                while( en.hasMoreElements() )
                {
                    permission = (Permission)en.nextElement();
                    if ( !permissions.implies( permission ) )
                    {
                        permissions.add( permission );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return (permissions == null)?new Permissions():permissions;
    }

    public PermissionCollection getPermissions(ProtectionDomain pd)
    {
        PermissionCollection permissions = null;
        List<Principal> principalList = new ArrayList<Principal>();
        for (Principal test : pd.getPrincipals()) {
            principalList.add(test);
        }

        Iterator<Principal> iterator = principalList.iterator();
        Principal principal = null;

        while( iterator.hasNext() )
        {
            principal = (Principal)iterator.next();
            PermissionCollection principalPerm = null;

            try
            {
                principalPerm = PermissionManager.getInstance().
                    getPrincipalPermissions(principal.getClass().getName(),
                                principal.getName(), pd.getCodeSource(), false);
            }
            catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (permissions == null)
            {
                permissions = principalPerm;
            }
            else
            {
                Enumeration<?> en = principalPerm.elements();
                Permission permission = null;
                while( en.hasMoreElements() )
                {
                    permission = (Permission)en.nextElement();
                    if ( !permissions.implies( permission ) )
                    {
                        permissions.add( permission );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return (permissions == null)?new Permissions():permissions;
    }
}
```

My problem is that for some reason, this has killed all of the permission checks for the application. The java security policy file seems to be ignored after changing things to use the java.security.Policy class. Whenever permission for a server action is checked with the AccessController, the application's ProtectionDomains don't have any of the grants assigned in the security.policy file, and I'm given a java.security.AccessControlException: access denied.

I'm not getting any warnings or errors during deployment. It simply seems like it can't find the file. This doesn't make any sense to me, as I haven't changed any configuration files or VM arguments. For debugging, I made the file as simple as possible:

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Still nothing. I'm not even sure if the application is trying to load a security policy when the manager extends off of java.security.Policy. I added -Djava.security.debug=policy to my VM arguments and nothing comes up. It doesn't appear to be loading anything, not even default Java policies. The console is blank. When I extend off of javax.security.auth.Policy, I see everything you would expect - policy grants, evaluations, etc.

The application does not use a security manager, but I did try implementing one (both via the VM argument -Djava.security.manager and in code with System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());) just to see if that helped, and it only made things worse - nothing could execute. The ojdbc6.jar was denied from testing a database connection right at server start.

Simply flipping the imports in the above class back to javax.security.auth.Policy fixes everything. Flipping it back causes access denied errors and no permission grants from my policy file. I've been reading through everything I can find about Java security policy implementation, but I haven't found anything that explains this.

Comment: So you extended the java policy class, that looks OK. How did you propagate that change to the rest of the application?

Comment: I just updated the import in the other classes that use the Policy class. That's it. Changed
    import javax.security.auth.Policy
to
    import java.security.Policy

Comment: For the runtime to use your custom implementation, either a) invoke `java.security.Policy.setPolicy(java.security.Policy)`, or b) change the value of `policy.provider` in `<JRE>/lib/security/java.security`, or c) register it programmatically via the `java.security.Provider` SPI.

Comment: I would get rid of it and use a properly constructed .policy file, or maybe no security manager at all.